# How can i find the key of a random picken value from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am a beginner of Python. I have made a dictionary of Lists. I want to pick a random value and then to know the key of that value. Is that possible?
e.g.

```
`lex = {"q1": [["B",  "A", "C", "D"],["2" ,"D"]],
       "q2": [["C", "A", "Z", "D"],["W","K"]],
       "q3": [["A", "K", "D", "C"],["me", "S"]],
       "q4": [["B", "L", "A", "F"],[ "1974", "D"]]}

        lex_list = list(lex.values())
        pick_value = random.sample(lex_list,1)`
```

Is there a way to know which is the key of the random value ? My purpose is to delete that pick_value from the list.Any suggestion is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you have an underlying goal, what is it? Looping through a dictionary to get the key from a value is inefficient (and ambiguous in case there are duplicated values). What are you really trying to achieve here? ;)

Comment: Im trying to make a multiple choice quiz. Suppose I have 50 questions in a Dictionary.
Of these 50 questions, e.g. 10 should be chosen at random. But every time a question is selected ,I want to be deleted from the list.

Comment: You could just have indexes of questions used and no deletion would be needed; generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 50 and get those questions by id

Comment: @Drako Nice thought..i'll test this also if my strategy not work. Thank you

Comment: that's cheaper computation wise rather than manipulating dictionary even in specific case with only 50 entries - probably does not matter how you do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your goal is to find the key of the random value selected and then delete it. The below code does that. Also keep in mind if there are duplicate values
in your dictionary, the code will delete the first key:value pair found with that value.

In duplicates case, a list of all keys need to be found and then deleted in a separate for loop. pick_value is a nested list hence pick_value[0] works here.

The new_list generated has the pick_value deleted.

```
for key,value in lex.items():
  if value == pick_value[0]:
    lex.pop(key)
    break
new_list = list(lex.values())
```

Comment: Thank you Hatim. That  was very helpful. In my dictionary there are no same keys or values ,that's why i thought of this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in both the key *and* the value of the random pick, then why don't you consider randomly choosing one key, and gathering the value of that key?

```
import random
lex = {"q1": [["B",  "A", "C", "D"],["2" ,"D"]],
       "q2": [["C", "A", "Z", "D"],["W","K"]],
       "q3": [["A", "K", "D", "C"],["me", "S"]],
       "q4": [["B", "L", "A", "F"],[ "1974", "D"]]}

# Randomly pick one key
r_key = random.choice(list(lex.keys()))
# Get the value corresponding to that key
r_value = lex[r_key]
print(r_key, r_value)
```

This uses [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick one element from an iterable.
This outputs:

```py
q4 [['B', 'L', 'A', 'F'], ['1974', 'D']]
```

---

If you ***really*** would rather continue with your strategy where you already have the random value, but want the corresponding random key(s), then this might work:

```
import random
lex = {"q1": [["B",  "A", "C", "D"],["2" ,"D"]],
       "q2": [["C", "A", "Z", "D"],["W","K"]],
       "q3": [["A", "K", "D", "C"],["me", "S"]],
       "q4": [["B", "L", "A", "F"],[ "1974", "D"]]}

lex_list = list(lex.values())
pick_value = random.sample(lex_list,1)

# Find the corresponding key(s)
keys = [key for key, value in lex.items() if value == pick_value[0]]
print(keys)
```

This outputs e.g. `['q2']`. Keep in mind that I keep referring to key*s* as multiple, because in theory it's possible for multiple keys to correspond to the same values. If this doesn't happen in your program, then you can just take `keys[0]` as your key.

The strategy uses a list comprehension to loop over the key-value pairs from `lex`, and then filters on `value` corresponds to `pick_value`.

Again, I recommend the first strategy.

Comment: Thank you,very good answer . I know i can do this but its not a helpful method for the purpose of  my code. I have to rearrange the whole algorithm.

Comment: That's understandable @fotonio. I've edited my answer to include an alternative approach which does answer exactly what you were after (or so I hope).

Comment: Thanks again Tom. Keys are the number of questions in my dictionary so there are no same keys or values. My strategy is to delete the  value from the list (not the Dictionary) every time is randomly picked. The problem arose when, by random selection, the same question was asked twice.